# how do i fix my Discord.py automod cog problem

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am working on the auto mod section of my discord.py bot but I keep getting the same error and for some reason I am stumped. I have checked the Documentation, and searched around google and can't seem to find what I need to do

```
from asyncio import sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from re import search
from typing import Optional

from better_profanity import profanity
from discord import Embed, Member, NotFound, Object
from discord.utils import find
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Cog, Greedy, Converter
from discord.ext.commands import CheckFailure, BadArgument
from discord.ext.commands import command, has_permissions, 
bot_has_permissions
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from Helix.bot import client

global database_name
database_name = 'discord'
global cnx
global cursor

profanity.load_censor_words_from_file("./data/profanity.txt")


class BannedUser(Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, arg):
        if ctx.guild.me.guild_permissions.ban_members:
            if arg.isdigit():
                try:
                    return (await 
ctx.guild.fetch_ban(Object(id=int(arg)))).user
                except NotFound:
                    raise BadArgument

        banned = [e.user for e in await ctx.guild.bans()]
        if banned:
            if (user := find(lambda u: str(u) == arg, banned)) is not None:
                return user
            else:
                raise BadArgument


class Mod(Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

        self.url_regex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))"
        self.links_allowed = ()
        self.images_allowed = ()

    async def kick_members(self, message, targets, reason):
        for target in targets:
            if (message.guild.me.top_role.position > target.top_role.position
                    and not target.guild_permissions.administrator):
                await target.kick(reason=reason)

                embed = Embed(title="Member kicked",
                              colour=0xDD2222,
                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

                embed.set_thumbnail(url=target.avatar_url)

                 fields = [("Member", f"{target.name} a.k.a. {target.display_name}", False),
                      ("Actioned by", message.author.display_name, False),
                      ("Reason", reason, False)]

            for name, value, inline in fields:
                embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

            await self.log_channel.send(embed=embed)

@command(name="kick")
@bot_has_permissions(kick_members=True)
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick_command(self, ctx, targets: Greedy[Member], *, reason: Optional[str] = "No reason provided."):
    if not len(targets):
        await ctx.send("One or more required arguments are missing.")

    else:
        await self.kick_members(ctx.message, targets, reason)
        await ctx.send("Action complete.")

@kick_command.error
async def kick_command_error(self, ctx, exc):
    if isinstance(exc, CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("Insufficient permissions to perform that task.")

async def ban_members(self, message, targets, reason):
    for target in targets:
        if (message.guild.me.top_role.position > target.top_role.position
                and not target.guild_permissions.administrator):
            await target.ban(reason=reason)

            embed = Embed(title="Member banned",
                          colour=0xDD2222,
                          timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

            embed.set_thumbnail(url=target.avatar_url)

            fields = [("Member", f"{target.name} a.k.a. {target.display_name}", False),
                      ("Actioned by", message.author.display_name, False),
                      ("Reason", reason, False)]

            for name, value, inline in fields:
                embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

            await self.log_channel.send(embed=embed)

@command(name="ban")
@bot_has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban_command(self, ctx, targets: Greedy[Member], *, reason: Optional[str] = "No reason provided."):
    if not len(targets):
        await ctx.send("One or more required arguments are missing.")

    else:
        await self.ban_members(ctx.message, targets, reason)
        await ctx.send("Action complete.")

@ban_command.error
async def ban_command_error(self, ctx, exc):
    if isinstance(exc, CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("Insufficient permissions to perform that task.")

@command(name="unban")
@bot_has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban_command(self, ctx, targets: Greedy[BannedUser], *, reason: Optional[str] = "No reason provided."):
    if not len(targets):
        await ctx.send("One or more required arguments are missing.")

    else:
        for target in targets:
            await ctx.guild.unban(target, reason=reason)

            embed = Embed(title="Member unbanned",
                          colour=0xDD2222,
                          timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

            embed.set_thumbnail(url=target.avatar_url)

            fields = [("Member", target.name, False),
                      ("Actioned by", ctx.author.display_name, False),
                      ("Reason", reason, False)]

            for name, value, inline in fields:
                embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

            await self.log_channel.send(embed=embed)

        await ctx.send("Action complete.")

@command(name="clean", aliases=["purge"])
@bot_has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear_messages(self, ctx, targets: Greedy[Member], limit: Optional[int] = 1):
    def _check(message):
        return not len(targets) or message.author in targets

    if 0 < limit <= 100:
        with ctx.channel.typing():
            await ctx.message.delete()
            deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit, after=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=14),
                                              check=_check)

            await ctx.send(f"Deleted {len(deleted):,} messages.", delete_after=5)

    else:
        await ctx.send("The limit provided is not within acceptable bounds.")

    async for guild in client.fetch_guilds():
        database_name = guild.id
        try:
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
                host='*.*.*.*',
                user='admin',
                password='*************',
                database=f"{database_name}"
            )
            if cnx.is_connected():
                db_Info = cnx.get_server_info()
                print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
                cursor = cnx.cursor()
                cursor.execute("select database();")
                record = cursor.fetchone()
                print("You're connected to database: ", record)

        # exception occured
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
                print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
            elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
                print("Database does not exist")
            else:
                print(err)

async def mute_members(self, message, targets, hours, reason):
    unmutes = []

    for target in targets:
        if not self.mute_role in target.roles:
            if message.guild.me.top_role.position > target.top_role.position:
                role_ids = ",".join([str(r.id) for r in target.roles])
                end_time = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=hours) if hours else None

                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mutes VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                           target.id, role_ids, getattr(end_time, "isoformat", lambda: None)())
                cnx.commit()

                await target.edit(roles=[self.mute_role])

                embed = Embed(title="Member muted",
                              colour=0xDD2222,
                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

                embed.set_thumbnail(url=target.avatar_url)

                fields = [("Member", target.display_name, False),
                          ("Actioned by", message.author.display_name, False),
                          ("Duration", f"{hours:,} hour(s)" if hours else "Indefinite", False),
                          ("Reason", reason, False)]

                for name, value, inline in fields:
                    embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

                await self.log_channel.send(embed=embed)

                if hours:
                    unmutes.append(target)

    return unmutes

@command(name="mute")
@bot_has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True, manage_guild=True)
async def mute_command(self, ctx, targets: Greedy[Member], hours: Optional[int], *,
                       reason: Optional[str] = "No reason provided."):
    if not len(targets):
        await ctx.send("One or more required arguments are missing.")

    else:
        unmutes = await self.mute_members(ctx.message, targets, hours, reason)
        await ctx.send("Action complete.")

        if len(unmutes):
            await sleep(hours)
            await self.unmute_members(ctx.guild, targets)

@mute_command.error
async def mute_command_error(self, ctx, exc):
    if isinstance(exc, CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("Insufficient permissions to perform that task.")

async def unmute_members(self, guild, targets, *, reason="Mute time expired."):
    for target in targets:
        if self.mute_role in target.roles:
            role_ids = cursor.field("SELECT RoleIDs FROM mutes WHERE UserID = ?", target.id)
            roles = [guild.get_role(int(id_)) for id_ in role_ids.split(",") if len(id_)]

            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM mutes WHERE UserID = ?", target.id)
            cnx.commit()

            await target.edit(roles=roles)

            embed = Embed(title="Member unmuted",
                          colour=0xDD2222,
                          timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

            embed.set_thumbnail(url=target.avatar_url)

            fields = [("Member", target.display_name, False),
                      ("Reason", reason, False)]

            for name, value, inline in fields:
                embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

            await self.log_channel.send(embed=embed)

@command(name="unmute")
@bot_has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True, manage_guild=True)
async def unmute_command(self, ctx, targets: Greedy[Member], *, reason: Optional[str] = "No reason provided."):
    if not len(targets):
        await ctx.send("One or more required arguments is missing.")

    else:
        await self.unmute_members(ctx.guild, targets, reason=reason)

@command(name="addprofanity", aliases=["addswears", "addcurses"])
@has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def add_profanity(self, ctx, *words):
    with open("./data/profanity.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write("".join([f"{w}\n" for w in words]))

    profanity.load_censor_words_from_file("./data/profanity.txt")
    await ctx.send("Action complete.")

@command(name="delprofanity", aliases=["delswears", "delcurses"])
@has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def remove_profanity(self, ctx, *words):
    with open("./data/profanity.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        stored = [w.strip() for w in f.readlines()]

    with open("./data/profanity.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write("".join([f"{w}\n" for w in stored if w not in words]))

    profanity.load_censor_words_from_file("./data/profanity.txt")
    await ctx.send("Action complete.")

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        guild = await self.on_messgage.guild.id
        database_name = guild
        try:
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
                host='192.168.86.244',
                user='admin',
                password='Shellshocker93!',
                database=f"{database_name}"
            )
            if cnx.is_connected():
                db_Info = cnx.get_server_info()
                print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
                cursor = cnx.cursor()
                cursor.execute("select database();")
                record = cursor.fetchone()
                print("You're connected to database: ", record)
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
                print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
            elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
                print("Database does not exist")
            else:
                print(err)

        selection = ("SELECT word FROM blacklist;")
        words = []
        words.append(cursor.execute(selection))
        print(words)

    def _check(m):
        return (m.author == message.author
                and len(m.mentions)
                and (datetime.utcnow() - m.created_at).seconds < 60)

    if not message.author.client:
        if len(list(filter(lambda m: _check(m), self.client.cached_messages))) >= 3:
            await client.message.channel.send("Don't spam mentions!", delete_after=10)
            unmutes = await self.mute_members(message, [message.author], 5, reason="Mention spam")

            if len(unmutes):
                await sleep(5)
                await self.unmute_members(message.guild, [message.author])

        elif profanity.contains_profanity(message.content):
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("You can't use that word here.", delete_after=10)

    # XX commented out so it doesn't interfere with the rest of the server while recording
    # elif message.channel.id not in self.links_allowed and search(self.url_regex, message.content):
    #   await message.delete()
    #   await message.channel.send("You can't send links in this channel.", delete_after=10)

    # elif (message.channel.id not in self.images_allowed
    #   and any([hasattr(a, "width") for a in message.attachments])):
    #   await message.delete()
    #   await message.channel.send("You can't send images here.", delete_after=10)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Mod(client))
```

so what I need to do is pull the guild id from a message and make it connect to the database  of like name to access my blacklist table for said server , however as stated before I can't seem to find how to do it.

I have the following Error codes when it goes to run the cog after a message is sent with a blatant test to a word stored in the table.

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "I:\HELIX\Dependencies\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in 
_run_event
     await coro(*args, **kwargs)
   File "I:\HELIX\Modules\Discord\Helix\cogs\auto_mod.py", line 311, in on_message
     guild = await self.message.guild.id
 AttributeError: 'Mod' object has no attribute 'message'
 Ignoring exception in on_message
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "I:\HELIX\Dependencies\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in 
 _run_event
     await coro(*args, **kwargs)
 TypeError: on_message() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given}
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you.
Also I know the indents are correct on my code they just won't be on here.

Comment: is it in a class? you have some errors except the one you've listed but first if its inside a class it shouldn't say this error

Comment: ill add the whole cog for better perspective then

Comment: your code is very and I mean very messy don't put functions inside of other functions your staff is not inside the class your indentation is none exiting I will write an answer but I will focus on the discord.py problem on the error you get now you have to use python indentation correctly to read more about it [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so except for the big indentation problem you have that I already commented on you have some discord.py problems there

```py
@Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    guild = message.guild.id
    database_name = guild
```

you have the message object that you get from the [on_message event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) from there you can access the guild and then the id. the await is not needed there your accessing a property of a Message object and not calling an async function

Comment: Thank you that actually fixed the problem now I can move forward. And your comment about the indentation did make me check over again and i found that i did mess up on one spot